# Overlap of two general distributions

Tags: probability-distributions

Say I have two random variables X and Y from the same class of distributions, but with different means and variances (X and Y are parameterized differently). Say the variance converges to zero as a function of n, but the mean is not a function of n. Can it be formally proven, without giving the actual pdf of X and Y, that their overlap area (defined the integral over the entire domain of min(f,g), where f,g are the respective pdfs) converges to zero when n goes to infinity? Perhaps this is too obvious...?

Comment: Yes, use the Chebyshev Inequality (Wikipedia).  Probably should have called the random variables $X_n$, $Y_n$.

Comment: What do you mean by "their overlap area"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. Let's assume the means verify $\mu_X < \mu_Y$, and let $c =(\mu_X +\mu_Y)/2$ the middle point. The "overlap area" (?) is

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \min(f_X(x),f_Y(x)) dx = \int_{-\infty}^c \cdots  dx + \int_{c}^{\infty} \cdots dx$$

The second term is:

$$\int_c^{\infty} \min(f_X(x),f_Y(x)) dx \le \int_c^{\infty} f_X(x) dx =P(X \ge c) \le P\left(|X - \mu_X| \ge \epsilon\right)\le \frac{\sigma_X^2}{\epsilon^2}$$

where $\epsilon = c/2$, and we've used the [Chebyshev's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality). Because the variance $\sigma_X^2$ tends to zero, so does this term; and the same goes to the other. Then,
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \min(f_X(x),f_Y(x)) dx \to 0$

Answer (score 0):

As long as the means are different, when variances go to zero, overlap goes to nothing.

Comment: This is indeed the conclusion the OP is interested in and, presumably, cannot reach...

Comment: Maybe one could appeal to an argument based on measure theory, such that any point other than the two means has measure zero attached to it.

Comment: If you have a solution, please post it here. Otherwise, I suggest to avoid presenting as a solution a mere rephrasing of the question.